# How can a Druid obtain certain high level Wizard/Cleric/Sorcerer spells?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells, optimization, druid

I'm building a Druid. The thing is, he's also a cult leader, meaning he would appreciate certain spells and skills that most Druids normally wouldn't need.  Unfortunately, from what I've seen so far, Druids don't get a lot of good spells like Dominate Person or even Charm Person, and they don't even get spells that hide alignment.  I've already solved the Charm Person problem by having a Symbol of Persuasion permanencied onto his person, but spells like Dominate Person and Undetectable Alignment are still missing.

He has a number of other items that have made it difficult for me to find a slot for a Ring of Mindshielding, and I know scrolls are a thing, but those also cost money I don't have because of other magic items I've given him.  I would also rather not change his class to Sorcerer or Wizard (that would ruin his character), or multiclass him into oblivion.  Cleric is not an option at all, multiclass or otherwise, for character and lore reasons.

I am still open to multiclassing, but only if it involves 2 levels or less.  He already has a one-level dip in Urban Druid for skill proficiencies and bonuses.

He is 18th level, and the only feat I have picked out for him, that is non-negotiable, is Natural Spell (because duh).  I would prefer feat recommendations if such feats exist, for accessing spells from the wiz/sorc and/or cleric spell lists without multiclassing, but I am also open to item recommendations.  Also, if there are any Druid spells I'm overlooking that serve similar purposes, please let me know.

Comment: What do you mean "for skill proficiencies and bonuses"?  That's non-standard terminology for 3.5.

Comment: Also, is it not an option to simply have this druid have allies to cast the spells he does not have access to?

Comment: Uh, sorry!  I don't typically differentiate terminology across editions...  I mean class skills and bonuses to those class skills.  Urban Druid fills in every social skill that Druid doesn't have and also gives some other useful skills Druid lacks.

Comment: He is technically an NPC.  I am playing him because I've been asked to help come up with content for a campaign setting a friend of mine is going to be DMing his first campaign in.  Being a cult leader, he doesn't have many allies who would be close enough to him to be casting those spells for him, nor would he trust anyone with the task very easily.  He would rather do it himself.  I can ask my DM about that, but I would rather know what my options are for him being as self-sufficient as possible in that respect.

Comment: Have you already investigated and found wanting the possibility of gaining limited access to the desired spells *via* the *summon nature's ally* line of spells?

Comment: I haven't looked heavily into that line yet, but taking a look at the full list of all the creatures available, there don't seem to be any that possess the spells I'm looking for.  Pixies look somewhat useful, though.

Comment: Did you try to use Google? Did you read [this guide](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?296803-Pathfinder-mini-guide-Casting-spells-from-other-lists), for example?

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy 3.5 and Pathfinder are not the same thing. You would be wise to recognize this fact; that’s twice in two days *that I have seen* that you have been pushing PF-specific material in 3.5-specific discussions.

Comment: @Baskakov_Dmitriy, like the dude above me said, that's Pathfinder stuff.  My DM, and to my understanding most DMs, doesn't allow Pathfinder stuff.

Comment: @KRyan Just have to get used to the fact that when you google for "3.5e Reincarnate" (or smth other with 3.5e word) you get links to d20PFSRD frequently, and to PF guides.

Answer (score 9):

There certainly are options here.

- The Mother Cyst feat from *Libris Mortis* grants a series of spells known that revolve around necrotic cysts, several of which are relevant to you.

  The horrifying effectiveness of this feat led to its being the central, foundational pillar of [Brian Bullsun-Stanton’s brutal magical surveillance state](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/51145/4563). That dip in urban druid could also be valuable—the *susurrus of the city* spell that is uniquely found on the urban druid list plays a big role as well.

  Specific highlights:

  - The 2nd-level *necrotic cyst* implants a necrotic cyst as an instantaneous effect (read: the only way to get rid of it is to surgically dig it out, if the target even knows it’s there). This, among other things, gives the target a −2 penalty on Necromancy spells, allows the rest of the spells from the feat to target this person, and prevents *protection from evil et al.* from blocking the other spells offered by the feat.
  - The 2nd-level *necrotic scrying* is a no-save scry on anyone who has a necrotic cyst. Never lose track of a cultist again.
  - The 4th-level *necrotic domination* works like *dominate person* except that it is Necromancy [Evil], not Enchantment [Mind-Affecting] (and it requires the target to have a cyst). This means it ignores mind-affecting immunity, cannot be blocked by *protection from evil*, **and** the subject takes that −2 penalty on the save.
  - Various other spells from the feat allow for extremely reliable punishments to be meted out to those who have cysts, which can provide a lot of influence and control even when not actively dominating someone.
- The Gatekeeper Initiate feat from *Eberron Campaign Setting* adds *mind blank*; the rest aren’t particularly stunning, but *mind blank* really is just that good.
- The Greensinger Initiate feat from *Eberron Campaign Setting* adds *charm person*, *charm monster*, and *mass charm monster*, among others.
- The rainbow servant prestige class from *Complete Divine* adds **all cleric spells** to your spell list. That requires 10 levels, though (note: the class is officially/technically full-casting, because the text says so and text trumps the 6/10 spellcasting listed on the table).
- Find a domain that has the spell(s) you want, and you will probably have little trouble getting it.

  - A *domain staff* from *Complete Champion* allows you to cast each spell of the given domain 1/day from your regular slots. No frills, and a bargain at 36,000 gp, but you can only attune to one at a time (done while preparing divine spells).
  - If you want more than one domain, or have a problem holding a staff, a *domain icon* from *Faiths of Eberron* allows you to burn a use of turn/rebuke undead in order to spontaneously swap a spell to the spell of the corresponding level from the domain that the icon represents. You can get turn undead from a single level of sacred exorcist from *Complete Divine* without losing any spellcasting. That level dip is a fairly significant cost, but once you’ve done it the *domain icons* themselves cost just 10,000 gp.
  - The Arcane Disciple feat adds the spells from one domain to the spell list of “one class [that has] arcane spellcasting ability.” With the Southern Magician feat from *Races of Faerûn* or the Alternate Source Spell feat from *Dragon* vol. 325, that could arguably be your druid class. (Note: if you go with this trick, it also opens up another of other options since arcanists have more prestige classes that do this kind of thing than priests do.)
  - The contemplative prestige class from *Complete Divine* is full-casting, and grants a bonus domain at 1st and again at 6th. Can be any domain appropriate to your faith.
  - The church inquisitor prestige class from *Complete Divine* grants the Inquisition Domain at 1st; stuff like *zone of truth*, *detect thoughts*, and *discern lies* might be quite useful.
  - The divine oracle prestige class from *Complete Divine* (noticing a theme?) grants the Oracle Domain at 1st; that one has a number of useful divinations.

Comment: Greensinger Initiate is BEAUTIFUL

Comment: Uh where can I find the domain staff?  I tried looking and can't find it.

Comment: @Carly It's in *Magic Item Compendium*, I can get you a page number in the morning.

Comment: That would be great.  I tried googling "domain staff" and also searching for items in the Magic Item Compendium, but it didn't come up.

Comment: @Carly The reason you had such difficulties is because I am a dumb, and repeatedly cited the wrong book *despite* having gone and looked it up, not found it, and then found it in the correct book. They’re in *Complete Champion*, not *Magic Item Compendium*, page 143.

Comment: Alright well I have it now so all is well.